# Удалить n символов в начале каждой строки в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как удалить n символов в начале каждой строки в файле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
lines = open(path, 'r').readlines()
with open(path, 'w') as fp:
    for line in lines:
        line = line[n:]  # вот тут можно воткнуть любую обработку, например
        fp.write(line)
```

Comment: Рекомендую читать файлы не readlines() методом, а в виде chunk-ами. Подробнее тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Comment: Необходимость в этом зависит от размера файла, не стоит заниматься преждевременными оптимизациями.

Comment: Две строки это преждевременная оптимизация ? ;) По читайте код после слов "If the file is line-based, the file object is already a lazy generator of lines:"

Comment: Если вы про `for line in open(path, 'r')`, то это будут уже не совсем те чанки. В любом случае, придётся загрузить файл в память целиком, потому что записывать результат надо в него же. Или в другой файл, а потом переименовывать. Но это всё опять преждевременные оптимизации.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'sdfasfdas'
>>> if len(s) > 3:
...     s1 = s[3:]
...
>>> s1
'asfdas'
>>>
```

Вы об этом?

Comment: по сути да, но нужен был вариант из файла в файл

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы изменить файл без загрузки его целиком в память, можно использовать временный файл, например, неявно с помощью `fileinput` модуля:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    print(line[n:] or '\n', end='')
```